# Isolation level for single SELECT query with PHP mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions, isolation-level

I have an InnoDB database with one table, *book*. In addition, I have a PHP script which contains one single query, to display the number of books in such *book* table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book
```

As you know, with the *mysqli* extension, it is possible to create a transaction with *mysqli_begin_transaction*. Next, the isolation level can be defined.

In my case, I don't need transactions related functions, and I use *mysqli_query*, because it's only a single SELECT query. However, I know that even a single query is wrapped under a transaction with MySQL, and the default isolation level is REPEATABLE READ.

The problem is here: I don't want REPEATABLE READ overhead for just executing such single query. READ UNCOMMITTED is enough.

Question: is the mysqli_extension auto-detect that I'm using a single SELECT query (because I don't begin any transaction) and automatically set the isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED (or at most READ COMMITED) or do I need to define a wrap class to always set READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level before executing such transaction-with-only-one-SELECT-query ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it a real problem or you are solving an imaginary issue?

Comment: I don't know why you think it's an imaginary issue. My example is simplified to show the principle, but of course, it's a real problem. I want the best performance for my web application which made very lot of such SELECT-single-query. So I think that using READ UNCOMMITED instead of REPEATABLE READ when I precisely don't need REPEATABLE READ can be a good start to relieve my MySQL database by deleting any REPEATABLE READ overhead. So, my question is: how PHP/MySQLi extension handle such single-SELECT-query case in terms of isolation level ? Thanks.

Comment: "I want the best performance" --- that's why I asked about performance. Can you **measure** the difference between using different isolation levels?

Comment: I can't measure easily: to know the real global gain, I need to turn all concerned *mysqli_query* to *mysqli_begin_transaction* schemes (with correct isolation level) on my PHP sources in productions servers. That's why I just want to know if the mysqli extension automatically set the READ UNCOMMITED isolation level when I call mysqli_query with one SELECT query. In this case, I even don't have to make any change in this area, and I can try to 
reducing the load by other ways.

Comment: So if you cannot measure it - how would you know that the optimization was successful? You cannot handle what you cannot measure. That's the performance optimization 101

Comment: I can't easily measure doesn't mean I can't measure. As I have said my production MySQL server and PHP scripts are in production and running. Obviously, I can evaluate the global load for my current installation. As it's too heavy, I'm just trying to find some ways to reduce it. That's why I ask about the behavior of mysqli_query. If there is improvement possible, I will edit my code, and then re-evaluate my global load to see if it's acceptable. Thank you for your time, but if you don't know an answer to a clearly initial formulate question, the next time, please just don't reply!

Comment: you've got an answer. It recommends you to perform another query. So - do you honestly think that 2 queries with `READ UNCOMMITTED` is better than a single query with a default isolation level? Again, if you cannot measure it - how could you think if it's better or worse? "If there is improvement possible" --- how would you know if it's an improvement or degradation if you don't measure it? "if you don't know an answer to a clearly initial formulate question" --- I know the answer, but you don't like it.

Comment: In my opinion, if I set READ UNCOMMITTED as the default, the problem will remain the same, because I will have to reset all others transactions level each time as well to REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE. In addition, I think that in such case, even if I ask MySQL to reset each time isolation level, such queries just add a little bit more network traffic, but I honestly don't think it's an issue about mysql cpu load. Network is  not a concern, so I think the *skarist answer* is very relevant. And as I have said, I can measure the gain. But, again, if you have better answer, please just post it!

Comment: "I can measure the gain" --- it would be nice to see how much you gained in terms of mysql server CPU (and may be IO) and how much you've lost in terms of latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mysqli_query will not automatically change the isolation level. Connecting through mysqli is in many ways just like connecting via the mysql cli. In both cases you will get the default isolation level. And just like the cli, mysqli can't make any assumptions about what statements will be coming through the connection.

Anyway, if you have some good reasons to be concerned about the isolation level, I think you should just set it explicitly, e.g.:

```
$mysqli_connection->query("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
```

That way you can ensure you have the isolation level you want, and you can comment your reasons in the code.

Comment: You're welcome. However, if you are looking into this because of performance concerns, I doubt this will help much. Check this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719269/how-transaction-level-isolation-affects-performace-in-autocommit-mode-in-mysql  Also, there are aspects of innodb that are dependent on the hardware/OS configuration. You might for example want to check innodb_flush_method in the my.cnf In one installation (where I had no control of the hardware/OS) I ended up with setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 and innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC and saw 1000x fold increase

Comment: in performance. However, I wouldn't recommend those settings for highly sensitive data. I you get a crash with those settings you loose data.