# PHP MySQL Database Transaction

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario: **User 1** performs a high load job to insert update `table_1` with begin transaction at the very first line of the code then commits if everything went OK. While the job is running, **User 2** executes a query that updates the same table `table_1`.

Question: What will be the possible output of the job performed by **User 2**? As to what I've read, when doing db transactions associated tables will be locked.

Note: I'm speaking with the same database user

Comment: There are different "isolation levels" that the connection can use, which would determine the answer. I believe the most common scenario would have User 2 read "old" data until the commit occurs, but YMMV.

Comment: Is this the same as when different people use db user **User 1** and update the same `table`?

I mean

Person A use **User 1** and execute the high load and 
Person B use **User 1** and execute another query while high load is still processing

Comment: No, the user account hitting the database wouldn't matter here. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109879/isolation-level-for-single-select-query-with-php-mysqli-query and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html for reference -- looks like in PHP you need to set it via a separate query.